# TextView not getting set upon Fragment creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so apologies in advance if I'm asking in an improper way.

I'm trying to create a basic app in Kotlin, wherein I have a hamburger menu with some fragments in it. When the user clicks on the HomeFragment, I want to display a welcome message with his name (stored in a Shared Preferences object).

However, each time I click on the menu button to open the fragment, it crashes - even if I remove the whole username/shared prefs thing and just try to set some plain text.

Here is my `HomeFragment.kt` file:

```
package com.urmilshroff.kotlindemo

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


private const val ARG_PARAM1="param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2="param2"

class HomeFragment:Fragment()
{
    private var param1:String?=null
    private var param2:String?=null
    private var listener:OnFragmentInteractionListener?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1=it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2=it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater:LayoutInflater,container:ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState:Bundle?):View?
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val username=SharedPrefObj.getUsername(this.activity!!)
        textViewHello.text="Hi there, $username!"

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
    }

    fun onButtonPressed(uri:Uri)
    {
        listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context:Context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(context is OnFragmentInteractionListener)
        {
            listener=context
        }
        else
        {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString()+" must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach()
        listener=null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
    {
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri:Uri)
    }

    companion object
    {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance()=
                HomeFragment().apply {
                    arguments=Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1,param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2,param2)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

My `fragment_home.xml`, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewDesc"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.993" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="240dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="@string/text_view_desc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Crash log:

```
09-17 00:19:24.968 25279-25279/com.urmilshroff.kotlindemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.urmilshroff.kotlindemo, PID: 25279
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: textViewHello must not be null
        at com.urmilshroff.kotlindemo.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:37)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

It says that `textViewHello` must not be null, so I tried making it nullable yet it crashes. Not sure what's wrong. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textViewHello has not been initialized.

Initialise it like this:

```
val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false) 
val textViewHello: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello) as TextView
```

Add the above line before setting text on textview

final `onCreateView` will look like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false) 
    val username=SharedPrefObj.getUsername(this.activity!!)
    val textViewHello: TextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello) as TextView
    textViewHello.text="Hi there, $username!"
    return rootView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Kotlin Android Extentions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) in your project, so no need to call `findViewById` method anymore.

All you need to do is change your code to:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val username = SharedPrefObj.getUsername(this.activity!!)
    textViewHello.text = "Hi there, $username!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put below line in `onViewCreated` method. You need to override that method.

`textViewHello.text="Hi there, $username!"`

this will set the textview after it has been initiated in `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

You need use it in onViewCreated.

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr_my_fragment, container, false)
    }

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    setQRCode()
    initToolbar()
    clickEvents()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call method setText, but your TextView object actually is null. You need to initialize.
Before set text, you should make some step. 
1. Inflate view in variable

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
```

2. Find and connect xml object with class variable

```
val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello)
```

3. Now, you can call setText

```
textView.setText("Example text")
```

Just modify your onCreateView method

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello)
textView.setText("Example text")
```